# ADT stack with a dynamic array (revision 1)

Tags: c, memory-management, stack

Here's the second draft of my ADT stack code which I posted here [before](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106510/adt-stack-with-a-dynamic-array) after carrying out most of the improvements suggested there.

I decided to expose a function called `resize_stack` to adjust the size of the stack as desired by the user instead of doing it automatically.

#### stacklib.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef STACKLIB_H
#define STACKLIB_H


/* generic type pushed item_to the stack */    
/* in this case it's just an int */
typedef int item_t;

/* our stack data type */
typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    item_t *elements;
} stack;

/* interface to our new stack data type */
stack* create_stack(size_t capacity);
int push_stack(stack *mystack, item_t data);
item_t* pop_stack(stack *mystack);
void delete_stack(stack *mystack);
stack* resize_stack(stack *mystack, size_t capacity);

#endif
```

#### stacklib.c

```
#include "stacklib.h"

/* a helper function to handle exceptions */
void handle_error(const char* message)
{
    if(errno) {
        perror(message);
    } else {
        printf("Error: %s\n", message);
    }

    exit(1);
}


stack* create_stack(size_t capacity)
{
    stack *stack_ptr = malloc(sizeof(stack));

    if(stack_ptr == NULL)
        handle_error("Error while allocating memory.");

    item_t *elements_ptr = malloc(capacity*sizeof(item_t));

    if(elements_ptr == NULL) {
        free(stack_ptr);
        handle_error("Error while allocating memory.");
    }


    stack_ptr->size = 0;
    stack_ptr->capacity = capacity;
    stack_ptr->elements = elements_ptr;

    return stack_ptr;
}

void delete_stack(stack *mystack)
{
    free(mystack->elements);
    free(mystack);
}

/* Returns 0 on success, 1 on failure */
int push_stack(stack *mystack, item_t data)
{
    /* stack is full! */
    if(mystack->size == mystack->capacity) 
        return 1;

    mystack->elements[mystack->size++] = data;
    return 0;
}

/* Returns a pointer to the popped data or NULL if the stack is empty */
item_t* pop_stack(stack *mystack)
{
    if(mystack->size == 0) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return &mystack->elements[--mystack->size];
    }
}

/* Returns a pointer to the adjusted stack or NULL on failure */
stack* resize_stack(stack *mystack, size_t capacity)
{

    item_t *tmp = realloc(mystack->elements, sizeof(item_t) * capacity);
    if(tmp == NULL) 
        return NULL;
    mystack->elements = tmp;
    mystack->capacity = capacity;

    if(mystack->size > capacity)
        mystack->size = capacity;

    return mystack;

}
```

#### main.c

```
#include "stacklib.h"

int main(void){
    stack *my_stack = create_stack(20);
    item_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        push_stack(my_stack, i); 
    }

    resize_stack(my_stack, 10);

    item_t res, *item ;
    while((item = (item_t*)pop_stack(my_stack)) != NULL) {
        res = *item;
        printf("data: %d\n", res);
    }
    delete_stack(my_stack);
    printf("last item popped was  %d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks very nice, code is clean and readable, not much else to change, I think...

---

This is more of a personal preference, not an universal recommendation: One of the things I like about C is having fine control over memory allocations, thus making it a very good choice for systems with limited memory or very rudimentary memory allocators. Because of that, I like to avoid allocating memory whenever possible, so I would not allocate each `stack` instance on the heap with `malloc`. Rather, let the user decide where to place it, be on the program stack, as a global or heap-allocated. To do that change, you'd just have to remove that allocation from `create_stack` and one free from `delete_stack`, taking a pointer to an external object in create:

```
bool create_stack(stack* mystack, size_t capacity);
```

That might seem like a little thing, but forcing the user to dynamically allocate a `stack` object when it doesn't have to is suboptimal and can be a problem on systems that don't rely on virtual memory and have fragmentation issues.

---

I strongly recommend that you use `bool`eans instead of error codes when a function has only two possible outcomes, success or failure. There's no universal agreement on the meaning of error codes, e.g. some return 0 on success, some return 1, some return -1 on error, and so on. This can be a major source of confusion. Use the `bool` type from `<stdbool.h>` whenever it makes sense.

---

Avoid repeating types in your `malloc` calls. E.g.:

> ```
> item_t *elements_ptr = malloc(capacity*sizeof(item_t));
> ```

Can be refactored to:

```
item_t *elements_ptr = malloc(capacity * sizeof(*elements_ptr));
```

Notice that you can use the variable name in the `sizeof` expression, in this case dereferenced, since we want the size of the type itself, not the size of a pointer. Makes your life easier if you change the name of the type you are allocating; one less place to be updated.

---

Make sure to print errors to `stderr`. That's the traditional error output and allows users to filter errors from normal program output. Just replace the `printf` call in `handle_error` by [`fprintf(stderr)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/).

---

Two last tips:

You might want to allow the users of your stack to provide their own error handler. You can achieve that with [function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work).

All functions receive pointers to `stack`, which could be passed in as null by error or due to some memory allocation failure. You can [`assert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) that they are not null to trap errors early and ease the debugging efforts.